# Communication between Angular2+ app and Node.js after deploy

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, server

I have deployed my Angular 6 App and Node.js to the Linux server.

There are two separated folders

The first, I run ng serve --host=`**.**.**.***` to start Angular App

There is my Angular packege.json

[image]

My auth.service.ts

[image]

My Node.js server looks that

[image]

My folder hierarchy on a server

[image]

The server is Running on Port 3000

[image]

With my IP url in auth.server.ts I've got console error

[image]

And my question is "which port has to listen to my Node.js and which url I had to write in my auth.service to set up communication between them?"

Comment: `http://**.***.**.***:3000/api/...` in your auth.service.

Comment: How are you running your node application?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still got an error.

OPTIONS http://**.***.**.***:3000/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

Comment: I am assuming that your nodejs application is not running. Can you confirm it is running?

Comment: @Apar Adhikari Yes. Node.js is running on DigitalOcean with pm2 in autorun mode

Comment: @AparAdhikari I edited my question

Comment: I suggest you to try out your api using Postman first using the live url i.e. DigitalOcean instance IP. If you still get this error, I think you should look at your api.js code.